# Persisting form input over login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have this app where a user can write a review for a school. A user must sign in with Facebook to save a review. The problem is if a user is unsigned and writes a review, then signs in with Facebook they have to write the same review again.

I am trying to fix this by storing the review data form in sessions, but I cant quite make it work.

What is the proper rails way to do this?

**ReviewForm:**

```
<%= form_for [@school, Review.new] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <% if current_user %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review', :class => "btn" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review and sign me into facebook', :class => "btn" %>
    <% end %>
<%end %>
```

**ReviewController**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
        @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
        @review = @school.reviews.new(params[:review])

        @review.user_id = current_user.id

        if @review.save
            redirect_to @review.school, notice: "Review has been created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def new
        @school = School.find_by_id(params[:school_id])
        @review = Review.new
    end

    def save_review(school, review, rating)
        Review.create(:content => review, :school_id => school, 
                       :user_id => current_user, :rating => rating)
    end

    private 
    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
            # Save review data into sessions
            session[:school] = School.find(params[:school_id])
            session[:review] = params[:review]
            session[:rating] = params[:rating] 
            # Login the user to facebook
            redirect_to "/auth/facebook"
            # After login save review data for user
            save_review(session[:school], session[:review], session[:rating])
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why not require the user to login before they can see the write review section?

Comment: I thought about that, but it wouldn't be a great experience.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to learn more about RESTful resources. That same book I recommended as part of my answer, The Rails 3 Way, does a really good job of explaining it. Basically, there's no reason to add your own `save_review` action. You can and should use the seven default RESTful actions.

Comment: Removed my answer as it only seemed to be raising more questions. I would give the solution proposed by @JasonSwett a go. If that doesn't work I recommend you check out http://rails-bestpractices.com/questions/21-best-way-to-retry-post-after-logging-user-in which is more or less exactly what you're doing

Comment: why don't you try cookies instead of session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the review in the create sessions action (which is not included in your question).  Assuming you are using omniauth, you can add something on the action that handles the callback

```
# review controller
def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    # Save review data into sessions
    session[:school] = School.find(params[:school_id])
    session[:review] = params[:review]
    session[:rating] = params[:rating]

    # Login the user to facebook
    redirect_to "/auth/facebook"   
  end
end

# callback to login the user
def handle_callback
  # do your thing here to login the user
  # once you have the user logged in
  if signed_in?
    if session[:school] && session[:review] && session[:rating] # or just 1 check
      Review.create(
        content: session.delete(:review),
        school_id: session.delete(:school), 
        user_id: current_user.id,
        rating: session.delete(:rating)
      )
      #redirect_to somewhere
    end
  end
end
```

I used delete so the session will be cleared of these values.

UPDATE: since you're using a session controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 

      if session[:school] && session[:review] && session[:rating] # or just 1 check
        review = Review.new
        review.content = session.delete(:review)
        review.school_id = session.delete(:school)
        review.user_id = user.id
        review.rating = session.delete(:rating)
        review.save
      end
    end

    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: This looks nice, but it dosent save anything to the db.

Comment: that really doesn't help.  can you update your question with the code that you use to handle the callback if you are using omniauth? or if not, the code that authorizes users.

Comment: i think that's what registers/finds the user.  i'm more interested in whatever is calling that.

Comment: yep that's the one.  i'm not sure why you have that `after_sign_in_path` method but you can add the `Review.create` block in there (also change the name of the method to what it actually does). i'll update my answer

Comment: Alright, but this mass-assign protected attributes. Is there another way around? Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: school_id, user_id

Comment: You need to whitelist your review attributes, add `attr_accessible :school_id, :user_id` to your review model.

Comment: Yes I know that, but that leaves a security issue.

Comment: I havent had the time to test this yet. but it looks alright, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that it's not "The Rails Way" to store things in the session besides really tiny stuff like a user token, etc. You can read more about that idea in The Rails 3 Way by Obie Fernandez.

I would recommend that you store reviews in the database right from the start and only "surface" the review after the review has been connected to a Facebook-authenticated user. If you have any curiosities regarding how to accomplish that, I'm happy to elaborate.

**Edit**: here's a little sample code. First I'd take care of associating users with reviews, for "permanent" storage. You could just add a `user_id` to the `review` table, but it would probably be `null` most of the time, and that seems sloppy to me:

```
$ rails g model UserReview review_id:references, user_id:references
```

Then I'd create a `user_session_review` table with a `review_id` and a `user_session_token`. This is for "temporary" storage:

```
$ rails g model UserSessionReview review_id:integer, user_session_token:string
```

Then when a user signs up, associate any "temporary" reviews with that user:

```
class User
  has_many :user_reviews
  has_many :reviews, through: :user_reviews
  has_many :user_session_reviews

  def associate_reviews_from_token(user_session_token)
    temp_reviews = UserSessionReview.find_all_by_user_session_token(user_session_token)
    temp_reviews.each do |temp_review|
      user_reviews.create!(review_id: temp_review.review_id)
      temp_review.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

So in your controller, you might do

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # some stuff
    @user.associate_reviews_from_token(cookies[:user_session_token])
  end
end
```

You'll of course have to read between the lines a little bit, but I think that should get you going.

**Edit 2**: To delete old abandoned reviews, I'd do something like this:

```
class UserSessionReview
  scope :old, -> { where('created_at < ?', Time.zone.now - 1.month) }
end
```

Then, in a cron job:

```
UserSessionReview.old.destroy_all
```

Comment: How can you determine which review to surface when the record is being created without a parent? Also what do you do with the reviews that remain unsurfaced? i.e., review is written but user looses interest and never logs in.

Comment: I'd probably use a `user_session_review` table with attributes `session_token` and `review_id`. For "abandoned" reviews, I'd probably clear unassociated reviews of a certain age every so often.

Comment: Sounds good on paper to me, if you show some example code you'll have my upvote. :)

Comment: Cyle - why did you remove your code? Jason Sweet - that process looks so complicated for something small like this.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake It was starting to get too out of hand and it only seemed to be producing errors in your code so I removed it. If Jason's solution doesn't work for you I suggest you try the link in the comment I added to your question. Rather than storing individual attributes inside the session (which seems kind of hacky) you should just store the entire params hash inside the session and then relay the create review request after the user signs in (as shown in the example code). At the end of the day your `SessionsController` shouldn't even know about how to create a review, it's a code smell.