# Rails HashWithIndifferentAccess - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am saving a hash session like this:

```
 session[:review] = {:content => params[:review], :rating => params[:rating], :school_id => params[:school_id]}
```

And when I save it to the database like this:

```
Review.create!(:content => session[:review][:content], :school_id => session[:review][:school_id], :user_id => current_user, :rating => session[:review][:rating])
```

It saves the value into one column like this:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
rating: '1'
content: somehting skjnfjkbf
```

Why and how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is record creating in database or not?? What do you mean by `one column`??

Comment: Yes it saves it to the db, but I have table like this review{id, content, rating, school_id, user_id} and it saves everything with this form: --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
rating: '1'
content: somehting skjnfjkbf into the content column.

Comment: could you paste the value of `Review.last` and `Review.last.content` ??

Comment: what's on params[:review]? it looks like params[:review] is a hash with indifferent access and you are assigning it to "content", then rails serializes the hash and saves that to the database, you should try debugging what's inside each of the values you are assigning to the review object before creation (i guess your rating for example is not in params[:rating], it's params[:review][:rating], and the content is params[:review][:content]) You should post the code of the form too

Comment: codeit - it returns a string, arieljuod check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072189/persisting-form-input-over-login

Comment: You don't have any rating and school_id fields in your form. And the `params[:review][:content]` is what you need to store at :content` key.

Comment: I have a field for rating but not for school_id.

Comment: ok. then may be changing the session hash to `session[:review] = {:content => params[:review][:content], :rating => params[:review][:rating], :school_id => params[:review][:school_id]}` and adding a field(may be hidden field or adding a logic to get the school_id) for school_id should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I am not sure how the error is produced.

But, below code should solve your problem.

```
Review.create!(session[:review].merge(user_id: current_user))
```